# PHP REGEX How to verify the exact format of the user input

Tags: php, regex

Regex is not my friend. He would find a good man to help me.
User can specify working time in the format: `00:00-12:30` or `00:00-12:30,14:15-18:00`

I would therefore need to verify the input complies with the variants, but nothing else should pass. I tried to combine pieces like

```
[0-9] {2} [0-9] {2}
```

But I really do not understand: /

Comment: need the : between too

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: You can't have the spaces in there like that either. Your regex essentially says `2 numbers followed space with quantity 2...etc`. Every character in a regex has meaning, even if it is just that literal character.

Comment: Ranges for regex are long and overly complicated. You should add your PHP usage attempt, it is unclear to me if you used `[0-9] {2} [0-9] {2}` or some parts of that with other code.

Comment: Regex should be used to validate a format, not content. Once you start validating that the numbers are between x and y and more, they get tons more complicated or even likely can't be done at all (for example, comparing that a is less than b). They can be done by much better tools. For example, to validate a number is between 0 and 23, you can either say `if($number >= 0 && $number <= 23)` or you can use a regex like: `/^([01]?[\d|2[0-3])$/`. Which would you think is easier to understand?

Comment: So I would have to `/^([01]?[\d|2[0-3]):([01]?[\d|5[0-9])-([01]?[\d|2[0-3]):([01]?[\d|5[0-9])$/` ?
And if it is to be that longer input so there would be a comma and the same again?

Comment: Use [this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/7u2WSJ/1). In PHP, you may shorten it to [`^((?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d)-(?1)(?:,(?1)-(?1))?$`](https://regex101.com/r/7u2WSJ/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I kiss your hands and of course thank everyone who contributed, I understood something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
'~^((?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d)-(?1)(?:,(?1)-(?1))?$~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7u2WSJ/2)

It matches

- `^` - the start of string
- `((?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d)` - a capturing group #1 that matches:

  - `(?:[01]\d|2[0-3])` - either of the two alternatives:

    - `[01]\d` - `0` or `1` followed with any digit
    - `|` - or
    - `2[0-3]`  - `2` followed with a digit from `0` to `3`
  - `:` - a colon
  - `[0-5]` - a digit from `0` to `5`
  - `\d` - any digit
- `-` - a hyphen
- `(?1)` - the pattern defined inside Group 1
- `(?:,(?1)-(?1))?` - an optional sequence (`?` at the end makes the regex engine match the patterns inside the non-capturing `(?:...)` match 1 or 0 times) that matches

  - `,` - a comma
  - `(?1)-(?1)` - Group 1 pattern, `-` and again Group 1 pattern
- `$` - end of string

Note that the `(?1)` is a [*subroutine call*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) that is used to reuse a part of the pattern inside `(...)` capturing parentheses. `(?1)` means *take the pattern defined in the first pair of unescaped parentheses in the pattern*.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go.

`((?&hh_mm))-((?&hh_mm))(?:,((?&hh_mm))-((?&hh_mm)))?(?(DEFINE)(?<hh_mm>(?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d))`

https://regex101.com/r/lUQHun/1

Capture groups provided for `hh:mm` of each part.

Expanded

```
 ( (?&hh_mm) )                 # (1), hh:mm
 -                             # -
 ( (?&hh_mm) )                 # (2), hh:mm

 (?:                           # Optional 
      ,                             # ,
      ( (?&hh_mm) )                 # (3), hh:mm
      -                             # -
      ( (?&hh_mm) )                 # (4), hh:mm
 )?
 (?(DEFINE)
      (?<hh_mm>                    
           (?: [01] \d | 2 [0-3] )
           :
           [0-5] \d 
      )                            
 )
```